# How to make IP address for vagrant ssh the same as for the VM?

Tags: ssh, vagrant

How can I make IP address for vagrant ssh the same as for the VM? What would I need to change/add to my manifest (Vagrant config files) ?

To explain my situation a little more: In my /etc/hosts file, I've setup local domains to map to the IP address of the VM as 192.168.56.105 - this is what is configured in the Vagrant setup, this works.

However `vagrant ssh` tries to connect to 127.0.0.1

Why would this be?

My vagrant ssh details are (when outputted to a file):

`Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/rdavis/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My specific problem had a root cause in port collision (with other VMs I'm using). Full credit to my colleague for spotting this.

Vagrant detects port collision but in your Vagrantfile config you have to *do something about it* i.e.

`auto_correct: true`

https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html

This means that I can run more than one VM at a time without this issue.