# Vagrant not connecting to private ip address

Tags: ssh, server, vagrant

I am totally new to SSH and Vagrant so this might be a really noob question..

I am trying to connect to a private IP address on vagrant by defining my server like below :

```
  config.vm.define "server" do |server|
    server.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.1.10"
    server.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000
    server.vm.synced_folder "./sync_folder", "/vagrant"
  end
```

after that, did all the vagrant up command and everything.
but when i typed in vagrant ssh-config on the command line..

```
Host server
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User ubuntu
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/xxxx
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

It is returning a local ip address and not the private ip address that I want. I don't understand why..

Comment: This is very similar to another question on stack overflow -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036663/how-to-make-ip-address-for-vagrant-ssh-the-same-as-for-the-vm?rq=1

but the answer did not seem to work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how vagrant is working, actually it creates multiple network interfaces so you do not necessarily see the expected one from your host.

If you look the output of the `vagrant up` command you'll see the following

```
...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
...
```

so clearly to ssh-in into the VM it uses the loopback address on port 22.

if you go to the VM and look the network interfaces

```
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:58:f3:11:f2:f2
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::58:f3ff:fe11:f2f2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22381 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10950 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:17387008 (17.3 MB)  TX bytes:690514 (690.5 KB)

enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:1f:f8:27
          inet addr:192.168.33.10  Bcast:192.168.33.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe1f:f827/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:522 (522.0 B)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)
```

The first interface is the NAT and this is the one vagrant uses to communicate (ssh) between the host and the VM, so this one is bind with the loopback from the host on a given port (by default this is 22 but if you have multiple VM running, vagrant will define another port)

The second interface is the interface you have setup from your Vagrantfile and has the IP assigned.

You could argue that `vagrant ssh-config` does not display all network interfaces properties but really this is about the ssh properties only and in this way the output is correct. If you want to get the network properties, you need to look into the VM

PS: final note, if you assign a private IP to your VM, you do not need to forward port, since you'll reach the VM directly using its IP.

Comment: I see! Thank you for the answer, pretty much spent an hour trying to fix a non-existing problem..

Comment: I had installed concourse on the VM that i stood up using Vagrant on my Mac. I have assigned a static IP for the vm but when I hit the ip:8080 on my browser, I am getting "not able to reach" error.I have both the NAT and host only adapters.